# Is it possible to access global variable on different nodes/agents in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I declared a global variable def my_var in my pipeline script on a node and setting the value for the variable on a node dev and on the downstream job(which is running on a different node-test) I'm trying to access the my_var value

Upstream Job:

```
def my_var
pipeline {  
agent none;
parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "${CHANGE_BRANCH}", description: 'This is a parameter', name: 'PARAMETER01')
}

 stages {
  stage('PR'){
  agent {node 'dev'}
   steps{
       script{
          my_var = "${env.PARAMETER01}"
       }
      build job: 'PR-Job',  parameters: [text(name: 'testParam', value: "${my_var}")]
    }
  }
}
```

Downstream Job(PR-Job):

```
pipeline {  
agent none;
stages {
    stage('PrintParameter'){
      agent {node 'test'}
        steps{
            sh "echo ${testParam}"            

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to add the parameter to your downstream job.

```
pipeline {  
    parameters {
        string(name: 'testParam', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }
...
}
```